# Why is there an error in my date format in my csv file?

Tags: python

```
from datetime import datetime
with open('directory.csv','r') as file:
    r=csv.reader(file)
    for i in r:
        if i[0]!='     NAME     ':
            data = sorted(r, key = lambda row: datetime.strptime(row[1], "%y/%m/%d"))
    print(data)
```

the above is my code.
and this is the output that comes:

```
ValueError: time data '2002/3/13' does not match format '%y/%m/%d'
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Y` needs to be capitalized

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2002/3/13', '%Y/%m/%d')
datetime.datetime(2002, 3, 13, 0, 0)
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

> `%y` Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number. (00, 01, ..., 99)
>
> `%Y` Year with century as a decimal number (0001, 0002, …, 2013, 2014, …, 9998, 9999)

Comment: ValueError: time data '2/2/2' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'                 this is what arises now

Comment: Would that date represent 02 Feb 2002? Your date formats are not consistent in that case, as you seem to have mixed `%Y` and `%y` formats in your data.

Comment: i changed it to year with century. i have a header which i do not want to include. but when i do that, my first record is not seen or recorded for the sorting